# Hikari Connection Pool - Slow , Block , Connection is not available : SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

**Problem:**

I have a springboot application which has hikari configured (auto). I'm getting error

> Connection is not available, request timed out after 30113ms

when I just do an insert operation in database and flow is like Controller > Service > Repository > save(entity) also not using @Transactional in repository, but the result is the same if I use it.

1. While load test 50request/1sec to this service sequentially getting success for 20-30 requests? remaining failed with below exception.

   ```
   2019-03-28 20:58:29.507 ERROR 90260 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-234] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

   java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30113ms.
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:697) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
   ```

   I am doing kind of load testing as triggering 50req/1sec and half and half getting success and failure. Enabled leak detection also but no trace in log.
2. Am I overdoing the configurations for this test or should I need to tune the pool connections? or it supports only that much?
3. Also hikari getconnection after 2nd request and subsequent requests takes almost increased 5+ seconds (blocks) why? Its not parallel why? Please help me or guide me on how much I need to tune to accept like 200 request per 1 min.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: demo
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 20000
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximum-pool-size: 50
      idle-timeout: 300000
      max-lifetime: 1200000
      auto-commit: true
      driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      jdbc-url:: jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=sample
      username: username
      leak-detection-threshold: 30000
```

**BootApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Sample{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
    }

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
     HikariDataSource dataSource=new HikariDataSource();
          //configuring pass from vault
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**SampleService.java**

```
@Service
public class SampleService implements SampleService {
    @Autowired
    private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @Override
    public List<String> getAll() {
        return (List<String>) sampleRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public String saveOrUpdate(Sample obj) {
        return sampleRepository.save(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: How long do the requests take that do succeed? If you have a maximum of 50 connections in your pool, but a request takes longer than 1 second, then firing 50 requests per second is of course going to starve the pool because new requests come in when old requests are still in progress...

Comment: usually request takes constant 6 seconds to complete.

Comment: Then you need to either find a way to release connections quicker, or you need to increase your pool size to at least 300 (and ensure your database config allows that many connections!). Or you need to test with more realistic numbers. If your requirement is 200 requests per minute, why are you testing with 50 requests per second (or 3000 per minute)?

Comment: how do i release the connection quicker in spring boot jpa repository class is using the connection. Is there a way to do so? But then i can't define 10 seconds because upcoming request takes +2 and more seconds to grab the connection. Also i tried now like every 10 seconds 20 request. But it failed at the range of 5th min. constantly hikari connection taking time and resulting that exception.

Comment: By releasing quicker I meant that you need to find a way to improve performance so that you don't keep a connection for 6 seconds.